# Excel VBA clear contents of cells within set ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a issue getting the syntax right on the below few lines of code.
essentially i want Excel to remove the contents of certain ranges per row but I need to avoid cells in between those ranges which have important formulas in them. That's why i cant use the 'clear entire row contents' approach

Boiled down I'd like to clear the contents of the ranges "C(e):L(e)","N(e):V(e)")

But i'm going wrong with the syntax I think
any advice on this one?

```
   Dim e As Integer
For e = 14 To 213
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(e, 35).Value = "0" Then Range("C" & "e":"L" & "e").ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks for those solutions, both work from a Syntax point of view however now when i try ot run the code i get a 'Next without For' error. However the For statement is certainly there?

Comment: Maybe the next is on the wrong level (or indent if you like), remember that you need an `End If` if you use the multiline if in Barts answer and the `Next` should be placed below the `End If`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around the e or else it just evaluates as the text e rather than the number your referring to in the for-loop.

```
Dim e As Integer
For e = 14 To 213
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(e, 35).Value = "0" Then Range("C" & e & ":L" & e & ",N" & e & ":V" & e).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to a Range incorrectly, all variables has to be outside quote and Connected with &.

You can make several action in if with ending condition with "End if".

```
Dim e As Integer
For e = 14 To 213
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(e, 35).Value = "0" Then 
Activeworksheet.Range("C" & e & ":L" & e).ClearContents
Activeworksheet.Range("n" & e & ":v" & e).ClearContents
End if
```